# yarn logs - stdout and stderr became huge files - how to avoid that

Tags: log4j, hadoop-yarn, ambari

Dears friends and colleges

we have ambari cluster with hadoop version - 2.6.4 
cluster include 52 datanode machines , and the follwing issue is happened on 9 datanodes machines

so I will explain the problem:

We noticed about critical problem regarding the yarn logs

We saw that **stderr** and **stdout** are huge files
In our case sdb is the relevant disk and sdb size is **only 20G**
So in fact stderr and stdout are **7G** each file

So /grid/sdb became full

My question is – is it possible to limit this files?

```
[root@datanode04 container_e41_1549894743658_0020_02_000002]# df -h /grid/sdb
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         20G   20G  712K 100% /grid/sdb
[root@datanode04 container_e41_1549894743658_0020_02_000002]# pwd
/grid/sdb/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1549894743658_0020/container_e41_1549894743658_0020_02_000002
[root@datanode04 container_e41_1549894743658_0020_02_000002]# du -sh *
6.9G    stderr
6.9G    stdout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common scenario of getting large log files in hadoop cluster due to log accumulation as multiple services are running in hadoop cluster. If you are running with Ambari managed hadoop cluster you need to configure log4j.properties from Ambari. You can configure this for services running in you hadoop cluster. This will ensure log rotation and retention in your hadoop cluster.

Here is link for reference from hortonwork (HDP) where one can find information about configuring [log4j properties](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.2.0/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/upgrading_log_rotation_configuration.html) of different services running in hadoop cluster. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I am alos see that link , but we not found the relevant log4j configuration in order to limit  the files , please advice if you thinking about something specific ? or give example for stdout / stderr

Comment: Have you tried to adjust properties such as, e.g. Appender: org.apache.log4j. RollingFileAppender, Roll criteria: Every 100MB. Retention: 9 backup logs.

Comment: In Advanced yarn-log4j content section, find and replace the following properties and values:

Find: log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize=<value>MB

Replace: log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize={{yarn_rm_summary_log_max_backup_size}}MB

Find: log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex=<value>

Replace: log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex={{yarn_rm_summary_log_number_of_backup_files}}